# Ubintu 13.04 hangs after install and reboot

Tags: gnome

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on an empty 34GB partition from an USB stick. It installed OK, and after reboot, it booted GNOME3, had shown the GNOME3 UI, and the mouse cursor. And then it hung immediately. No reaction to mouse events; extremely slow reaction to Numlock keyboard (Numlock LED switches its state extremely slowly); the hard disk LED is switching on and off slowly. I waited a few dozens of minutes, no luck.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

After a reboot, please attach copies of your **/var/log/dmesg** and **/ver/log/syslog** files to this thread